# AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute 'set_completer_delims'

Tags: python-3.x, readline

```
    >>> import pdb
    >>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    >>> y = 6
    >>> z = 7
    >>> r1 = y+z
    >>> r1
    13
    >>> r2 = x+y
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
    >>> pdb.set_trace()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1585, in set_trace
        Pdb().set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 156, in __init__
        readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n`@#$%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:\'",<>?')
    AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute 'set_completer_delims'
    >>>
```

Whats problem? run python3.6 an error occurred
I just try to pdb on Cygwin. 
(Note that other lib is okay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was fixed by installing pyreadline:

```
pip install pyreadline
```

Please try it.

More info: https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/544

Comment: Unfortunately not the solution for using pdb inside a python script in lldb with the same error.